# CDI Injection into a FacesConverter

Tags: jsf-2, cdi, myfaces

From just a few searches, this seems like a problem that has been around for a while.  I have written a FacesConverter that looks like the following.  The object **Category** is a JPA entity and **CategoryControl** is the DAO that fetches it.

```
@FacesConverter(value = "categoryConverter")
public class CategoryConverter implements Converter {

@Inject private CategoryControl cc;

public CategoryConverter() { }

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    if (cc != null) return cc.getByName(value);
    System.out.println("CategoryConverter().getAsObject(): no injection!");
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    if (!(value instanceof Category)) return null;
    return ((Category) value).getName();
}

}
```

As you probably guessed by now, I never get the injection.  I got this workaround from [this page](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/EXTCDI-127), which looks like this.:

```
Workaround for this problem: create this method in your localeController: 

public Converter getConverter() 
{ 
    return   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().createConverter("localeConverter"); 
} 

and use converter="#{localeController.converter}" in your h:selectOneMenu.
```

However I can't make this work either.  My backing bean creates and returns a converter all right, but it doesn't get the object injected into it.

I am using MyFaces CODI 1.0.1. With the current GlassFish/Weld container.  Can anyone suggest a solution before I re-code to not use a Converter?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Replace

```
@FacesConverter(value = "categoryConverter")
```

by

```
@Named
```

and use

```
<h:inputSomething converter="#{categoryConverter}" />
```

or

```
<f:converter binding="#{categoryConverter}" />
```

instead of

```
<h:inputSomething converter="categoryConverter" />
```

or

```
<f:converter converterId="categoryConverter" />
```

By the way, similar problem exist for `@EJB` inside a `@FacesConverter`. It however offers a way to be grabbed by JNDI manually. See also [Communication in JSF 2.0 - Getting an EJB in @FacesConverter and @FacesValidator](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#GettingAnEJBInFacesConverterAndFacesValidator). This way you can use a `@FacesConverter(forClass=Category.class)` without manually defining it everytime. Unfortunately I can't tell from top of head how to realize that for CDI beans.

---

**Update**: if you happen to use JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), since version 1.6 is adds transparent support for using `@Inject` and `@EJB` in a `@FacesConverter` class without any additional configuration or annotations. See also [the CDI `@FacesConverter` showcase example](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/FacesConverter).

Comment: Well I'll be dambed.  I implemented a workaround that basically calls the application to evaluate an expression from inside the converter, but I think this is more elegant.  So I have another question @BalusC -- isn't about time you wrote a book on JSF?

Comment: Well it isn't like you would have to write much -- just edit all the stuff you have written already.  Seriously I have thought of an outline for a book if you are interested in a collaboration just let me know.

Comment: Well can you believe it almost exactly one year after the original posting I run into this problem again on a new project, do a google search, and come with my own post!  I don't remember writing the above but computers never lie.

Comment: @BalusC Like many other of your answers, people link to this one to this day, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183176/jsf-converter-for-selectonemenu. You might consider editing to include the support provided by Omnifaces in 1.6 once it's out :)

Comment: The [SelectItemsConverter](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsConverter) from  [OmniFaces] (http://code.google.com/p/omnifaces/) project save my day. Thanks @BalusC!

Comment: @BalusC You don't have to write a book. You should marry me.

Answer (score 7):

The `@Inject` Annotation only works in CDI managed instances. If you want to use CDI features inside a non-CDI managed instance (Like a JSF Validator or a JSF Converter) you can just programm against the CDI API.

This works only in at least Java EE 7 + CDI 1.1 server.

```
@FacesValidator("userNameValidator")
public class UserNameValidator implements Validator {

    private UserService userService;

    public UserNameValidator(){
        this.userService = CDI.current().select(UserService.class).get();
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
     ....
    }
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/CDI.html

With all the AnnotationHell in Java EE people forget how to code.

Answer (score 3):

Just use @Advanced of CODI for your @FacesConverter see the [Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/EXTCDI/JSF+Usage#JSFUsage-DependencyInjection).

> As soon as a converter or a validator is annotated with @Advanced it's possible to use @Inject.

Answer (score 2):

Per BalusC's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13156834/933054), I decided to add JSF (requestscoped) managed beans that only contained @FacesConverter and Converter to resolve this issue in my app, since I'm migrating from JSF managed beans to CDI managed beans.

I tried CODI @Advanced against @FacesConverter, but it does not inject the bean at all.