# @PostConstruct not working in @FacesValidator

Tags: jsf, validation, postconstruct

Is the post construct annotation not supported in validators?

I have a application scoped jndi servicelocator bean which I inject as a managed property into my validator.

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{jndiServiceLocatorBean}")
private final JndiServiceLocatorBean jndiServiceLocatorBean = null;
```

The post construct annotated method to initialize my necessary remote bean is never invoked and so my remote bean remains null.

```
private UserBeanRemote userBeanRemote = null;

@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct()
{
    this.userBeanRemote = (UserBeanRemote) this.jndiServiceLocatorBean.getRemoteBean(UserBeanRemote.class);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works only if the `Validator` is annotated as a `@ManagedBean` or `@Named` instead of `@FacesValidator`.

Just use the normal constructor instead.

```
@FacesValidator("fooValidator")
public class FooValidator implements Validator {

    private UserBeanRemote userBeanRemote;

    public FooValidator() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        JndiServiceLocatorBean jndiServiceLocatorBean = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{jndiServiceLocatorBean}", JndiServiceLocatorBean.class);
        this.userBeanRemote = (UserBeanRemote) jndiServiceLocatorBean.getRemoteBean(UserBeanRemote.class);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Support for dependency injection in JSF artifacts other than `@ManagedBean` is planned for [JSF 2.2](http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/) ([spec issue 763](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-763)).

#### See also:

- [How to inject in @FacesValidator with @EJB, @PersistenceContext, @Inject, @Autowired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572335/dependency-injection-in-facesvalidator-jsf-validation/7572413#7572413)
- [Communication in JSF 2.0 - Getting an EJB in `@FacesValidator` and `@FacesConverter`](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#GettingAnEJBInFacesConverterAndFacesValidator)

Comment: Jsf 2.2 will make many things much easier! So many good changes :) As a JavaEE newbie it is all confusing what works and what works not and why and why not.

Comment: It was really useful to know that the support for this is in plan for 2.2 Thanks BalusC

Comment: @Chin: unfortunately, `@FacesConverter`/`@FacesValidator` have to wait for 2.3. OmniFaces 1.6 will come with solution for JSF 2.0/2.1/2.2.