# How to access a local interfaces from one project into another within the same ear project

Tags: jsf-2, ejb, cdi

I have a web project that has FacesValidator, this validator needs to access an EJB service to verify if a record exists. Unfortunately, I cannot inject my enterprise beans since the validator is not a managed-bean, so I'm trying to access it via InitialContext. I've tried different combination from http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjf.html but failed.

What works is this format:

```
java:global/myProject-ear-1.0.0/myProject/MyService!com.czetsuya.myProject.service.membership.MyService,
```

My question is can it be simplify? Seems too long.

Thanks,

czetsuya

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the server logs. A bit decent EJB container (at least, Glassfish 3 and JBoss 6/7 do), logs all available JNDI names of the EJB during EJB deployment step. Provided that the validator is properly been put in the WAR and the EJB has a `@Local` interface, then the shortest JNDI name would be the `java:app` one which should in your case have been `java:app/myProject/MyService`.

A completely different alternative is to just make the validator a JSF or CDI managed bean instead, so that you can just use the `@EJB` annotation.

```
@ManagedBean // Or @Named.
@ApplicationScoped // Provided that the instance doesn't have any state.
public class MyValidator implements Validator {

    @EJB
    private MyService myService;

    // ...
}
```

and reference it by `binding` instead of `validatorId`:

```
<f:validator binding="#{myValidator}" />
```

Note that from JSF 2.2 on, you should be able to inject `@EJB` in a `@FacesValidator` (and `@FacesConverter`).

#### See also:

- [How to inject in @FacesValidator with @EJB, @PersistenceContext, @Inject, @Autowired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572335/dependency-injection-in-facesvalidator-jsf-validation/7572413#7572413)