# Inject cdi bean in Validator works, but breaks arquillian test

Tags: junit, dependency-injection, cdi, jboss-arquillian

I tried injecting a bean in my Validator and it didn't work. Then I did some googling and found: [How to inject in @FacesValidator with @EJB, @PersistenceContext, @Inject, @Autowired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572335/how-to-use-ejb-inject-and-or-autowired-in-facesvalidator)

I applied this method and it does work. It compiles and it does the job. But when I run my test (working with arquillian) then I'm getting the following stacktrace (my code can be found bellow):

```
org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.DeploymentException: Could not deploy to container: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".WeldService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".WeldService: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [BookBean] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject com.rd.rdtravel.Validator.NumberOfPersonsValidator.bookBean]"}}
at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.deploy(ArchiveDeployer.java:74)
at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.CommonDeployableContainer.deploy(CommonDeployableContainer.java:148)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:161)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:128)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.executeOperation(ContainerDeployController.java:271)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.deploy(ContainerDeployController.java:127)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.DeploymentExceptionHandler.verifyExpectedExceptionDuringDeploy(DeploymentExceptionHandler.java:50)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createDeploymentContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:78)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$1.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:95)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$1.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:80)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:263)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachManagedDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:239)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.deployManaged(ContainerDeployController.java:79)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:101)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:75)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeClass(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:80)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:182)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:199)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:147)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".WeldService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".WeldService: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [BookBean] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject com.rd.rdtravel.Validator.NumberOfPersonsValidator.bookBean]"}}
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.getActionResult(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:134)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.getResultFromNode(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:123)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.get(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.get(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:42)
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.executeDeploymentPlan(ArchiveDeployer.java:91)
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.deploy(ArchiveDeployer.java:58)
    ... 91 more
```

---

```
package com.rd.rdtravel.Validator;

//This annotations are needed to support injection in validators. This isn't supported by default.
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class NumberOfPersonsValidator implements Validator {
@Inject
BookBean bookBean;

@Override
public void validate(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    int numberOfPersons = (Integer) value;
    if (bookBean.getSelectedTrip().getAvailablePlaces() < numberOfPersons) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage();
        message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        message.setSummary("Trip can't have that many passengers.");
        message.setDetail("Trip can't have that many passengers.");
        facesContext.addMessage(null, message);
        throw new ValidatorException(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Bean:

```
@SessionScoped
@Named
public class BookBean implements Serializable {

//Some methodes and properties. Don't think they are important for this question.
}
```

My test:

```
public class LocaleBeanTest extends AbstractArquillianTest {
@Inject
private LocaleBean localeBean;

@Test
public void testChangeLocaleEN() {
    localeBean.changeLocale("en");
    assertEquals(localeBean.getLocale().getLanguage(), "en");
    }
}


@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public abstract class AbstractArquillianTest {

    @PersistenceContext
    public EntityManager entityManager;

    public static EntityManagerFactory emf;

    static Context context;

    @Resource
    public static UserTransaction tx;

    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive initializeEjb() {
        JavaArchive archive = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
                .addPackages(true, "com.rd.rdtravel")
                .addAsResource("META-INF/persistence.xml")
                .addAsResource("META-INF/beans.xml")
                .addAsResource("import.sql");

        System.out.println(archive.toString(true));

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        properties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
        properties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
        properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:4447");
        properties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "root");
        properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "rootroot");
        try {
            context = new InitialContext(properties);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return archive;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like you are missing something in your Deployment Archive that the BookBean depends on, maybe some external lib?

you can check the contents of the archive if you set the deploymentExportPath in the arquillian.xml to an apropriate path

like:

```
<engine>
   <property name="deploymentExportPath">target/arquillian</property>
</engine>
```