# Validation with an EJB service call, possible with JSF validator or JSR303 bean validation?

Tags: validation, jsf-2, ejb, bean-validation

i want to validate my username using a select. if the username already
is present in the database, validation fails.

i found some annotations for primefaces like this for example:

```
@Size(min=2,max=5)  
private String name;
```

i didnt found a annotation solution for something like this:

```
try {
    dao.findUserByUserName(userName);

    message = new FacesMessage ("Invalid username!", "Username Validation Error");
    message.setDetail("Username already exists!");
    message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);

    throw new ValidatorException(message);
} catch (NoSuchUserException e) {}
```

Do i have to use a custom validator or are there annotations for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *Do i have to use a custom validator or are there annotations for it?*

It can be done both ways.

In case of a custom JSF validator, you only need to understand that an EJB cannot be injected in a `@FacesValidator`. You've basically 3 options:

1. [manually obtain it from JNDI](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#GettingAnEJBInFacesConverterAndFacesValidator)
2. [or, make it a `@ManagedBean` instead of `@FacesValidator`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572335/how-to-use-ejb-inject-and-or-autowired-in-facesvalidator)
3. [or, install OmniFaces which adds transparent support for `@EJB` and `@Inject` in `@FacesValidator`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/FacesValidator)

Ultimately, you can end up like this, assuming that you went for the `@ManagedBean` approach:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class UsernameValidator implements Validator {

    @EJB
    private UserService service;

    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object submittedValue) throws ValidatorException {
        if (submittedValue == null) {
            return; // Let required="true" handle.
        }

        String username = (String) submittedValue;

        if (service.exist(username) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("Username already in use, choose another"));
        }
    }

}
```

Which is used as follows:

```
<h:inputText ... validator="#{usernameValidator}" />
```

In case of JSR303 bean validation, you'd need to create a [custom `@Constraint` annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints-constraintannotation) along with a [custom `ConstraintValidator`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints-validator). You need to make sure that you're using at least CDI 1.1, otherwise you can't inject an EJB in a `ConstraintValidator` and you'd need to resort to manually grabbing it from JNDI in `initialize()` method. You can't solve it by making it a managed bean and even OmniFaces hasn't any magic for this.

E.g.

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = UsernameValidator.class)
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
public @interface Username {
    String message() default "Username already in use, choose another";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

with

```
public class UsernameValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Username, String> {

    @EJB
    private UserService service;

    @Override
    public void initialize(Username constraintAnnotation) {
        // If not on CDI 1.1 yet, then you need to manually grab EJB from JNDI here.
    }

    Override
    public boolean isValid(String username, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return !service.exist(username);
    }

}
```

and in model

```
@Username
private String username;
```

Comment: Hm. i changed the annotations of my validation class to '@Named' and '@SessionScoped' and inserted validator="#{usernameValidator}" to my inputText and get the following: javax.el.ELException: Identity 'usernameValidator' does not reference a MethodExpression instance

Comment: Haven't seen this one before. What if you use `<f:validator binding="#{usernameValidator}"/>` instead?

Comment: If i do that he says that <f:validator cant be nested into panelgird: <f:validator> Parent not an instance of EditableValueHolder: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGrid. my form is inside a panelgrid and it should stay like that ^^

Comment: You're supposed to nest it in an `EditableValueHolder` component, such as `<h:inputText>`. Nest it inside the very same tag as where you originally used `validator` attribute.