# Dynamically preselect items in HtmlSelectOneMenu with OmniFaces SelectItemsConverter

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, selectonemenu, omnifaces

I want to dynamically create a dropdown (HtmlSelectOneMenu) with all possible options. The option currently set should be preselected. To achieve this I created a value expression for my form:

```
String jsfValue = String.format("#{%s.item.%s}", getControllerBeanName(), key);
ValueExpression valueExpression = JSFUtils.createValueExpression(jsfValue, String.class);
menu.setValueExpression("value", valueExpression);
```

The string `#{%s.item.%s}` evaluates to `#{playlistController.item.category}` and `category` is the object of type `Category` that I want to bind to my dropdown.

To use the `SelectItemsConverter` from OmniFaces I changed the `toString()` method of `Category` to:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return String.format("%s[id=%d]", getClass().getSimpleName(), getId());
}
```

My code for the form generation looks like this (Note: `Category` extends `BaseEntity`):

```
  private UIComponent createDropdown(FormInput property) {
    String key = property.getKey();
    String beanName = key + "Controller";
    GenFormBaseController controller = (GenFormBaseController) JSFUtils.getManagedBean(beanName);

    List<BaseEntity> list = controller.getService().findAll();
    List<SelectItem> selectItems = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
    for (BaseEntity itemInList : list) {
      selectItems.add(new SelectItem(itemInList, itemInList.getName()));
    }

    UISelectItems items = new UISelectItems();
    items.setValue(selectItems.toArray());

    HtmlSelectOneMenu menu = new HtmlSelectOneMenu();
    menu.setConverter(new SelectItemsConverter());
    menu.setId(key);
    menu.getChildren().add(items);

    String jsfValue = String.format("#{%s.item.%s}", getControllerBeanName(), key);
    ValueExpression valueExpression = JSFUtils.createValueExpression(jsfValue, String.class);
    menu.setValueExpression("value", valueExpression);

    return menu;
  }
```

If I set `menu.setConverter(new SelectItemsConverter());` then the wrong item is preselected. But If I remove it, then the correct item is selected but when I try to save the form it fails because it has no converter for the dropdown.

Can anyone help me? I've published the [code on GitHub](https://github.com/bennyn/wlc-webapp/blob/master/src/main/java/de/fhb/controller/GenFormBaseController.java). 
The method `createDropdown` can be found at the bottom of the linked code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error in the code. Simply the equals() and hashCode() of the BaseEntity were insufficient. And the error BalusC already mentioned. The resulting code looks like the following:

GenFormBaseController.java

```
private UIComponent createDropdown(FormInput property) {
  String key = property.getKey();
  Class<?> expectedType = property.getValue();

  String beanName = lowerFirstChar(expectedType.getSimpleName()) + "Controller";
  GenFormBaseController controller = (GenFormBaseController) JSFUtils.getManagedBean(beanName);

  List<BaseEntity> list = controller.getService().findAll();
  List<SelectItem> selectItems = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
  for (BaseEntity itemInList : list) {
    selectItems.add(new SelectItem(itemInList, itemInList.getName()));
  }

  UISelectItems items = new UISelectItems();
  items.setValue(selectItems);

  HtmlSelectOneMenu menu = new HtmlSelectOneMenu();
  menu.setConverter(new SelectItemsConverter());
  menu.setId(key);
  menu.getChildren().add(items);

  String jsfValue = String.format("#{%s.item.%s}", getControllerBeanName(), key);
  ValueExpression valueExpression = JSFUtils.createValueExpression(jsfValue, expectedType);
  menu.setValueExpression("value", valueExpression);

  return menu;
}
```

BaseEntity.java

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
  int hash = 7;
  hash = 97 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.id);
  return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if (obj == null) {
    return false;
  }
  if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
    return false;
  }
  final BaseEntity other = (BaseEntity) obj;
  if (!Objects.equals(this.id, other.id)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is here, in the `String.class` type argument:

```
ValueExpression valueExpression = JSFUtils.createValueExpression(jsfValue, String.class);
```

A `Category` is not a `String`. Use `Category.class` instead and everything should be well. At least, theoretically. I can't copy'n'paste'n'run this piece of code without changes.

Comment: Hi BalusC. Thank you for your answer. I've tried it and it did not work. But I made the following observations: When using "Category.class" in the value expression, then every item in the select box will be selected (<option value="Category[id=1]" selected="selected">). When using "String.class" and the "SelectItemsConverter" then nothing is selected. When I use "String.class" without a converter for the HtmlSelectOneMenu then the correct item will be selected but I cannot save the selected item because there is no converter for the select menu. Does this help in finding the problem?

Comment: You should have receivced a `Validation Error: Value is not valid` on submit then, but you didn't make a mention of it. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/9069660 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/17343582