# SelectOneMenu default value in edit mode

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a editable datatable, containing column "Datatype". When editing this column, a selectOneMenu is used to select a value "String", "Number" or "Date". When I enter the edit mode, the "Datatype" column is set to "String" (the first item of data type list), but I would like it to be the current value of this column (like in Primefaces showcase: [Click](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml) - for example if I click on a first row and third column of the second table, 'Fiat' should be selected and not the first item from selectOneMenu - 'BMW' -like in my case).

What could be the problem with my code?

xhtml:

```
<p:column headerText="Type" >
        <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.dataType.code}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{item.dataType}" converter="myConverter" >
                              <f:selectItems value="#{backingBean.dataTypeList}" var="dt" itemLabel="#{dt.code}" itemValue="#{dt}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

DataType class:

```
public class DataType implements Serializable {

    private BigDecimal id;
    private String code;
    private String descr;

    // Getters+Setters.
}
```

Using Primefaces 5.1.

I'm available for any additional information needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided that the `Converter` implementation as identified by `myConverter` is [properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848970/how-to-prepopulate-a-hselectonemenu-with-complex-objects-entities-from-a-db) doing its job, then this can happen if the entity in question, `DataType`, doesn't have `equals()` (and `hashCode()`) properly implemented.

Just add/autogenerate them in your entity. It should at least look like this:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return (id != null) 
        ? (getClass().hashCode() + id.hashCode())
        : super.hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    return (other != null && getClass() == other.getClass() && id != null)
        ? id.equals(((DataType) other).id)
        : (other == this);
}
```

This should also immediately solve the ["Validation Error: Value is not valid"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069379/validation-error-value-is-not-valid) error when submitting the form.

All your entities should have them implemented. To avoid repeating boileplate, consider creating a base entity where all your entities extend from. See also [Implement converters for entities with Java Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343032/implement-converters-for-entities-with-java-generics).