# Confused with PrimeFaces Converter (as it applies to selectOneMenu)

Tags: jsf, primefaces

The implementation of PlayersConverter in AutoComplete demo actually serves not only as a converter, but also as a loader for Players list. I am a bit weary of this model, as loading is already implemented in my project.
I don't understand why Converter interface was not implemented as template:

```
Converter<Players>
```

instead.

Yes, these demos look great, but seeing data being statically loaded into the lists inside the converters I can't figure how to use that in real life application, where converter should not really have anything to do with data loading.

Is it at all possible to use PrimeFaces converters without actually loading data in them? How can I inform a converter of the type of list item it is supposed to convert?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand that you're talking about `PlayerConverter` as shown in [this page](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/autoCompletePojo.jsf). This is just an extremely localized implementation for pure demonstration purposes (the showcase isn't using any DB and they have to get hold of those data *somewhere*). This is indeed confusing and misleading. In real world code, you should be interacting with the data from the database, something like follows:

```
@ManagedBean
public class PlayerConverter implements Converter {

    @EJB
    private PlayerService service;

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {
        if (submittedValue == null || submittedValue.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            return service.find(Integer.valueOf(submittedValue));
        } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion Error", "Not a valid player ID"));
        }
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object modelValue) {
        if (modelValue == null) {
            return "";
        }

        if (modelValue instanceof Player) {
            return String.valueOf(((Player) modelValue).getNumber());
        } else {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion Error", "Not a valid player instance"));
        }
    }
}
```

---

From your original question before the edit:

> *Further, when they write in their demos **converter="player"** what does **"player"** refer to?*

As to the `converter="player"`, it's just the value of the `<converter-id>` as registered in `faces-config.xml`. You can also register it via `@FacesConverter` annotation:

```
@FacesConverter("player") // I'd rather rename it to playerConverter.
public class PlayerConverter implements Converter {
    // ...
}
```

Note that my example uses `@ManagedBean` instead, otherwise using `@EJB` would not have been possible. See also [How to inject @EJB, @PersistenceContext, @Inject, @Autowired, etc in @FacesConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665673/jsf2-can-i-use-ejb-to-inject-a-service-into-a-facesconverter/7665768#7665768)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, I understand that the whole converter seems some kind of unnecessary code duplication. The JSF utility library OmniFaces has identified and solved this problem in flavor of [`omnifaces.ListConverter`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/ListConverter). Just use `converter="omnifaces.ListConverter"` instead of `converter="player"` and the whole converter class. Note that there's a similar converter for components using `<f:selectItem(s)>`, the [`omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsConverter).

Comment: I deleted the last part of the question just moments ago as I figured that FacesConverter annotation fixed that part. It's nowhere mentioned among the self-praises of PrimeFaces alluding to how easy to use it is. You are absolutely right as to the rest of points - writing converter for each of the list class items is exactly that - going back to writing redundant boilerplate code.

Comment: I added omnifaces jar to the compile time libraries in NetBeans, included xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions" into html tag and supplied converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" to the p:selectListBox. The namespace has a warning that it is not used and the list box stopped working. What am I missing?

Comment: Like as PrimeFaces and all other libraries, you need to install OmniFaces as well. See also https://code.google.com/p/omnifaces/. By the way, the converters doesn't require a XML namespace. Only the `<o:xxx>` components/taghandlers and `#{of:xxx()}` functions do.

Comment: It was added to the lib path as a jar.

Comment: Wait, are you using `omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter` on `<p:autoComplete>`? You should be using `omnifaces.ListConverter` as stated in the answer and showcase.

Comment: No, it's all right - I just forgot to undo the changes made to use PF converter. It just worked on the selects without any issues. It's almost working for the list view (only once and assigns to a wrong select, but that's my code and I just need to figure it out).