# Can't instantiate class, while populating selectonemenu in JSF2

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, selectonemenu

I'm trying to populate `selectOneMenu` from DB and I get run time error `Can't instantiate class`. I get

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at pointControllerConverter.getPoints(pointControllerConverter.java:89)
```

Any advice?

This is my code:

xhtml file:

```
    <p:selectOneMenu id="point" value="#{pointController.selectedPoint}"
                     var="items_var"> 

         <f:selectItems value="#{pointController.points}" var="points_var" 
                        itemLabel="#{points_var.name}" itemValue="#{points_var.name}"/>

    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Managed bean:

```
    @ManagedBean(name = "pointController")
    @SessionScoped

    public class PointController implements Serializable {

    @EJB
        private ethoam.entity.PointFacade ejbFacade;
        private List<point> points;
        private point selectedPoint;
        private point[] selectedPoints;
        private List<Point> selectedPointsList;
        private SelectItem[] PointNamesOptions;

        public PointController() {
                  this.initList();
        }

        @PostConstruct
        private void initList() {

        points = new ArrayList<point>(PointControllerConverter.getPoints().values());


    }

        // getters setters
     }
```

Converter class:

```
    public static class PointControllerConverter implements Converter {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "PointPU")
    private static EntityManager ejbfacade;

    public static Map<String, point> points = new HashMap<String, point>();

    public static Map<String,point> getPoints() {

    points = (Map<String, point>) ejbfacade.createNamedQuery("SELECT d FROM point d WHERE d.name = :name");
    return points;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value == null || value.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        PointController controller = (PointController) facesContext.getApplication().getELResolver().
                getValue(facesContext.getELContext(), null, "pointController");
        return controller.ejbFacade.find(getKey(value));
    }

    java.lang.Integer getKey(String value) {
        java.lang.Integer key;
        key = Integer.valueOf(value);
        return key;
    }

    String getStringKey(java.lang.Integer value) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(value);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object object) {
        if (object == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (object instanceof point) {
            point o = (point) object;
            return getStringKey(o.getIdPoint());
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("object " + object + " is of type " + object.getClass().getName() + "; expected type: " + Point.class.getName());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: PointControllerConverter and PointController classes are in the same package.

Comment: PointControllerConverter is a class reference.

Comment: Sorry about the confuse.. I didnt update the latest code. Actually  PointControllerConverter is a class reference with "P" and getPoints() method is static.

Comment: a STATIC entityManager instance? That just shouts "WRONG" at me.

Comment: Well if it is not static, i couldn't reference it from the static getPoints() method

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't be referencing it OUTSIDE of that static getPoints() then... You have to learn how to take hints that the design might be completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well first I don't know why you are using a Converter as a List supplier !

You might need to move `getPoints()` logic into a ManagedBean.

On the other hand the NullPointerException is caused due the failed injection of of the entity manager (which I don't know why it's a static).

In a Converter or Validator you can't inject using @PersistenceContext or @EJB

**See Why:** [How to inject @EJB, @PersistenceContext, @Inject, @Autowired, etc in @FacesConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665673/jsf2-can-i-use-ejb-to-inject-a-service-into-a-facesconverter)

You may do this:

```
Context envCtx = InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env");
EntityManager em =  (EntityManager) envCtx.lookup("persistence/PointPU");
```