# Difference between converter="entityConverter" and converter="#{entityConverter}"

Tags: jsf, converters, el

Is there any difference between `converter="entityConverter"` and `converter="#{entityConverter}"` ?

Initially, my application works as a charm with such code:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="civilityId"
                 value="#{customerController.selected.civilityId}"
                 converter="civilityConverter"> ...
```

but when I change `converter="civilityConverter"` to `converter="#{civilityConverter}"`,

I get this error :

```
Grave:   Error Rendering View[/customer/index.xhtml]
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /customer/Edit.xhtml @30,186
value="#{customerController.selected.civilityId}":
Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Although this is not specific to the `<p:selectOneMenu>`, it would be worthwhile to just check its [tag documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/5.0/core/primefaces-p/selectOneMenu.html) if it gives any hints. It says the following:

> Name: `converter`
>
> Type: `javax.el.ValueExpression`
>   (must evaluate to `java.faces.convert.Converter`)
>
> Description: An el expression or a literal text that defines a converter for the component. When it's an EL expression, it's resolved to a converter instance. In case it's a static text, it must refer to a converter id.

So, in case of

```
converter="entityConverter"
```

it will be resolved as a converter ID which is declared via either the `@FacesConverter` annotation on the converter class

```
@FacesConverter("entityConverter")
public class EntityConverter implements Converter {}
```

or the `<converter-id>` entry of `<converter>` registration in `faces-config.xml`:

```
<converter>
    <converter-id>entityConverter</converter-id>
    <converter-class>com.example.EntityConverter</converter-class>
</converter>
```

And, in case of

```
converter="#{entityConverter}"
```

it will be resolved as a concrete `Converter` instance in the EL context. The normal way to put such an instance in the EL context is to declare it as a managed bean. E.g. via JSF

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class EntityConverter implements Converter {}
```

or via CDI

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class EntityConverter implements Converter {}
```

This is often done so in order to be able to inject an `@EJB` into it, so that any necessary business/DB logic could be performed. Until the upcoming JSF 2.3, the `@FacesConverter` (and `@FacesValidator`) namely doesn't support dependency injection (which you could however work around by using JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/FacesConverter)).

#### See also:

- [How to inject @EJB, @PersistenceContext, @Inject, @Autowired, etc in @FacesConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665673/how-to-inject-ejb-persistencecontext-inject-autowired-etc-in-facesconve)
- [/Registration.xhtml @19,81 validator="#{UsernameValidator}": Identity 'UsernameValidator' was null and was unable to invoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551652/registration-xhtml-19-81-validator-usernamevalidator-identity-usernamev/)

Answer (score 1):

converter="civilityConverter" is for FacesConverters 
converter=#{civilityConverter} is for Named managed beans.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some useful information, I can add following thing.

I use `FacesConverter` and I have tested following **JSF** elements

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{controller.panelTpl.txtUser.value}">
    <f:converter converterId="userConverter"/>
    <f:selectItems 
        value="#{controller.panelTpl.txtOriginator.userList}"
        var="user" 
        itemLabel="#{user.humanName}"
        itemValue="#{user}"
        />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

and

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{controller.panelTpl.txtOriginator.value}">
    <f:converter converterId="#{userConverter}"/>
    <f:selectItems 
        value="#{controller.panelTpl.txtOriginator.userList}"
        var="user" 
        itemLabel="#{user.humanName}"
        itemValue="#{user}"
        />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The first  work correctly.

The second return following error

```
Severe:   JSF1006: Cannot instantiate converter of type 
Severe:   Expression Error: Named Object: ' not found.
javax.faces.FacesException: Expression Error: Named Object: ' not found.
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createConverter(ApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.createConverter(ApplicationWrapper.java:393)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ConverterTagHandlerDelegateImpl.createConverter(ConverterTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:158)
```

As Balus said, this is not only linked to Primefaces.

I use JSF 2.2 because I deploy my application on Glassfish 4.1.