# /Registration.xhtml @19,81 validator="#{UsernameValidator}": Identity 'UsernameValidator' was null and was unable to invoke

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2

This is my project structure:

[image]

This is in my XHTML file:

```
<h:inputText id="username" value="#{user.username}" required="true"
 validator="#{UsernameValidator}" />
 <h:message for="username"/>
```

And here is `UsernameValidator` class:

```
@FacesValidator("UsernameValidator")
public class UsernameValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "in validator class");
        if (String.valueOf(value).length() == 0 || String.valueOf(value).length() < 3) {
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Username Validation Failed", "Invalid Username");
            message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            throw new ValidatorException(message);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I write something in `username` field, This error happens:

> /Registration.xhtml @19,81 validator="#{UsernameValidator}": Identity 'UsernameValidator' was null and was unable to invoke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is here:

```
<h:inputText ... validator="#{UsernameValidator}" />
```

You're trying to reference a `@FacesValidator` as a managed bean. This won't work. The value in the `@FacesValidator` annotation represents the application-wide validator ID which is to be specified as a string, not a managed bean name.

So, below should do:

```
<h:inputText ... validator="UsernameValidator" />
```

True, you'll probably have seen code snippets wherein a validator (or converter) is referenced as a managed bean via `#{...}`. But in those cases they are *actually* also registered as a managed bean via `@ManagedBean` or `@Named` instead of `@FacesValidator` (or `@FacesConverter`).

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class UsernameValidator implements Validator {}
```

This is often done so in order to be able to inject an EJB into it so that any necessary business/DB logic could be performed.

#### See also:

- [How to inject in @FacesValidator with @EJB, @PersistenceContext, @Inject, @Autowired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572335/how-to-inject-in-facesvalidator-with-ejb-persistencecontext-inject-autow)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem: the below

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "in validator class");
```

Is a very, *very* bad way to perform "logging" in a **web** application. Please stop doing that.

Comment: @Tarik: test the "AFAIK".

Comment: sorry if my comment seems to be rude (it's not my intention, No one helped me to understand JSF as you did). But, I'm still confused, in the `h:inputText` [documentation](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/docs/2.0/pdldocs/facelets/h/inputText.html), it says regarding the `validator` attribute: MethodExpression representing a validator method that will be called during Process Validations to perform correctness checks on the value of this component. The expression must evaluate to a public method that takes FacesContext, UIComponent, and Object parameters, with a return type of void.

Answer (score 2):

*As your question was a little modified, I added a strikeout to the content related to your original question:*

<s>First, The application level validation include points 3 and 4 (Custom validation using Validator interface and Validation methods in backing beans) in addition to using Custom Component.</s>

It seems that you are mixing up Validation using bean methods and implementing custom validator classes (the two last ones), a quick refresh about this two approaches taking your code as an example :

## Validation with bean methods:

This is the most simple one, as hou will just need to add validation method to your class and invoke it through a method expression using the `validator` attribute, like your example :

```
<h:inputText id="username" value="#{user.username}" required="true" validator="#{usernameValidator}" /> 
// I changed to usernameValidator to respect naming conventions
```

But, in that case, `usernameValidator` is a method in the `user` `@ManagedBean`, something like this:

```
@ManagedBean("user")
@SessionScoped
public class User implements Serializable{

    // Please notice that this method should have the same signature as the validate method of the interface Validator 
    public void usernameValidator(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "in validator class");
        if (String.valueOf(value).length() == 0 || String.valueOf(value).length() < 3) {
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Username Validation Failed", "Invalid Username");
            message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            throw new ValidatorException(message);
        }
    }
}
```

## Custom Validator Classes:

The implementation for the Class is the same as what you did, which is implementing the `Validator` Interface, and registring the Validator by giving it and `ID` , *I will copy your exact code to make the answer clean*:

```
// I just changed the ID from UsernameValidator to usernameValidator
@FacesValidator("usernameValidator") 
public class UsernameValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "in validator class");
        if (String.valueOf(value).length() == 0 || String.valueOf(value).length() < 3) {
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Username Validation Failed", "Invalid Username");
            message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            throw new ValidatorException(message);
        }
    }
}
```

You can give and `ID` to your Validator by using annotation `@FacesValidator("usernameValidator")` (which you already did), **Or** in the `faces-config.xml` by adding the following:

```
<validator>
    <validator-id>usernameValidator</validator-id>
    <validator-class>yourpackage.UsernameValidator</validator-class>
</validator>
```

Then, you will use the same `ID` in the `f:validator` Tag, like this:

```
<h:inputText id="username" value="#{user.username}" required="true">
    <f:validator validatorId="usernameValidator" />
</h:inputText>
```

**NB:** This is **not** all validation appraoches in JSF, but I think that these two are the simplest ones for Custom validation which you can use in your example <s>(It's the 4 and 3 respectively in the list of JSF validation ways you provided)</s>.

**As additional information**, I will also give a brief review about the Built-in validation components which **doesn't fit** to your Code example:

## Built-in validation components:

JSF (I am talking about 2.0 as I am not sure if there is some new ones in JSF 2.2) has standard validators that you can use to validate:

- The length of `String` using `f:validateLength`
- A `double` / `long` value within an optional range using `f:validateDoubleRange` / `f:validateLongRange` respectivly.
- A `String` against a regular expression using `f:validateRegex`
- Required values using `f:validateRequired` or the attribute `required`

There is another alternative for using those Tags by using the `f:validator`, you can find a [good example here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/12/validator-for-multiple-fields.html#BasicExample).

### See also:

- [JSF 2.0 tutorial - Finetuning validation](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html#FinetuningValidation)
- [The Java EE 6 Tutorial - Creating and Using a Custom Validator](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnauw.html)
- [Custom validator in JSF 2.0](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-validator-in-jsf-2-0/)

Comment: It seems from Sajjad's example that he wants to write a custom Validator, in which case he only needs to add an <f:validator> tag.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes he can just add the `f:validator`,  but he need also to understand why using the `validator` attribute didn't worked, so it seems from his example that he is mixing the use of the `Validator` interface and validation methods. Once he understand the difference, he will be more able to choose the adequate solution for his functional requirement

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a problem in your Registration.xhtml file.  The validator requires a separate tag inside the <h:inputText> tag:

```
<h:inputText id="username" value="#{user.username}" required="true">
<f:validator validatorId="UsernameValidator" />
</h:inputText>

<h:message for="username" />
```

The error you have seems to be caused by JSF not being able to find the validation bean.  Your project directory looks OK but check to make sure the class file for UsernameValidator is there and can be read by your app server.