# @Inject doesn't work in @FacesConverter after upgrade GlassFish 4.1 to 4.1.1

Tags: jsf, null, converters, inject, mojarra

I have a problem with GlassFish 4.1.1 and Payara 4.1.153+.

The `@Inject` points in the POJO converters no longer work. What did I miss? Has something changed in FacesConverter?

```
@FacesConverter("bkkConverter")
public class BkkConverter implements Converter,Serializable
{

  @Inject
  private BkkBean bkkBean;
  ...
  bkkBean.fetchFromDatabase(...); <- NPE
```

The variable `bkkBean` remains `null` now. The `Converter` itself works (`getAsObject`/`getAsString`), but no `@Inject`?

It still works on GlassFish 4.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were relying on an unspecified/undocumented feature. Mojarra 2.2 unintentionally supported `@Inject` in `@FacesConverter`, `@FacesValidator` and `@FacesComponent` before version 2.2.9 as consequence of a forgotten experiment/rollback. The support is expected to come in Mojarra 2.3 whereby an additional annotation attribute is required as in `@FacesConverter(managed=true)`. See also a.o. [issue 3552](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3552).

In JSF 2.2 with CDI 1.1 your best bet is to manually grab the bean via [`CDI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/CDI.html) utility class.

```
BkkBean bkkBean = CDI.current().select(BkkBean.class).get();
// ...
```

Alternatively, you can install [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) in order to get transparent support for `@Inject` (and `@EJB`) in [`@FacesConverter`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/FacesConverter) and [`@FacesValidator`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/FacesValidator)

#### See also:

- [How to inject @EJB, @PersistenceContext, @Inject, @Autowired, etc in @FacesConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665673/how-to-inject-ejb-persistencecontext-inject-autowired-etc-in-facesconve)

Comment: WOHOO: i just read http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/FacesConverter and were suprised... thx - but how does the CDI-helper know about the session @BkkBean is using? i want to autocomplete jpa classes forth/back.