# Mojarra 2.3.0-m06, @PersistenceContext field is null

Tags: jsf, mojarra, jsf-2.3

I have such converter:

```
@FacesConverter(managed = true, value = "myConverter")
public class MyConverter implements Converter {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = MyService.PERSISTENCE_NAME)
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    ...
}
```

The problem is that *entityManager* is null. faces-config JSF version is 2.3, Mojarra 2.3.0-m06 is used. In the [Application#createConverter() implementation](https://github.com/omnifaces/mojarra/blob/b845e5d08549927b323ebdcca36bc7b01341db8e/jsf-ri/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/application/ApplicationImpl.java#L1349) it jumps into the first if's body, but doesn't create the converter. *entityManager* is not null when [the converter is a bean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7665768/1593938).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add a *beans.xml* file in the *WEB-INF* directory with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

Comment: Care to explain why you needed to add this? Did you find it mentioned anywhere?

Comment: I found an example of new features: https://github.com/AnghelLeonard/JSF-2.3/tree/master/JSF23InjectInConverterValidator. The only thing that differed my project from this example was this xml file. Then I found that this file is required in all CDI applications, but i didn't have any problems without it before.

Comment: @Kukeltje FacesConverter is not a bean defining annotation, so by default it would not be processed by CDI. Native JSF converters don't have support for injecting a persistence context, but CDI beans do (even though PersistenceContext itself is not a CDI injection, CDI beans just happen to integrate with it by default). That's why beans.xml is needed here.

Comment: p.s. without beans.xml, the managed=true attribute would be totally ignored. JSF 2.3 will try to locate a converter via CDI, but that would return nothing, then it would try to locate the converter natively, and it would find it. This is a bit of a caveat and is caused by JSF using the same Converter interface and annotation for what are essentially two very different things.