# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.faces.model.SelectItem

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to get the itemValue from a oneSelectMenu but this exception has returned.
Could anyone help me?

```
<p:outputLabel for="tipo" value="Tipo "/>
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="tipo" value="#{pessoaBean.pessoa.tipo}">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Cliente" itemValue="Cliente"/>
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Funcionário" itemValue="Funcionário"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: the error kind of speaks for itself

Comment: Could you help?

Comment: help with what? did you read the error message? you are trying to cast a String to a SelectItem. since there is no is-a relationship between the two, that's not possible

Comment: Please read [mcve]

Comment: As already mentioned by others, you should post the content of `pessoa` and `pessoaBean` so that someone might help you.

Comment: here a good exemple that explains what you get this error and what works :https://hobione.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/jsf-fselectitem-vs-javaxfacesmodelselectitem/

Comment: tipo from pessoa is a String ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to implement a javax.faces.Converter and add attribute `converter="..."` to `p:selectOneMenu`

see for example [How to inject @EJB, @PersistenceContext, @Inject, @Autowired, etc in @FacesConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665673/how-to-inject-ejb-persistencecontext-inject-autowired-etc-in-facesconve)