# Primefaces p:autocomplete with ajax sets value only once

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, autocomplete, primefaces

When I select value in p:autocomplete first time it fires set method. But when I try to select value once again nothing happens (according to debug it even doesn't fire setter)

In browser network monitor I see that there is the following string added to returned xml on select

```
<extension ln="primefaces"type="args">{"validationFailed":true}</extension>
```

But I don't use any validation there

primefaces version is 3.3.1

My faces code:

```
<p:autoComplete value="#{cityManager.kladrCity}"
                            completeMethod="#{cityManager.searchKladr}" var="p"
                            itemLabel="#{p.fullName}" itemValue="#{p}"
                            converter="#{kladrCityConverter}" id="kladrCity"
                            forceSelection="true">

                            <p:ajax event="itemSelect"
                                listener="#{cityManager.handleKladrSelect}" update="name zipCode" immediate="true"/>
                        </p:autoComplete>
```

Converter code:

```
@Named("kladrCityConverter")
public class KladrCityConverter implements Converter {
@Inject
private KladrService kladrService;

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String key) {
    if(key == null || key.trim().equals("")){
        return null;
    }

    KladrCity obj = kladrService.findById(key);

    return obj;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object obj) {
    if(obj == null){
        return "";
    }
    KladrCity kladrCity = (KladrCity) obj;
    return kladrCity.getCode();
}

}
```

Comment: If JSF cannot successfully convert an object, it will result in a validation error.  Place breakpoints in your converter to see if/where a conversion error is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
@Named("kladrCityConverter")
```

to

```
@FacesConverter("locationConverter")
```

Comment: This isn't the problem. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531449/cdi-injection-into-a-facesconverter