# FacesConverter Inject workaround - constructor alternative

Tags: jsf, cdi, inject

This is in relation to the workaround for the known issue of JSF FacesConverter not being an eligible @Inject target for CDI.  I followed the workaround at [CDI Injection into a FacesConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531449/cdi-injection-into-a-facesconverter?lq=1).  However, in my FacesConverter, I had been utilizing the feature of having the Class of the object passed into a constructor.

From the [javadoc](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.2/javadocs/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html) - "If a converter has a single argument constructor that takes a Class instance and the Class of the data to be converted is known at converter instantiation time, this constructor must be used to instantiate the converter instead of the zero-argument version."  This is in direct conflict with the CDI requirement for "normal scope" beans where a no-arg or @Inject annotated constructor is all that's allowed.

So in summary, I want to use a Converter that can take CDI Injections, and has access to the Class of the object being converted at runtime.

I am using Mojarra 2.2.4 on Glassfish 4 with Weld 2.0.4.

Comment: Have you read the "Update" section of the answer you found yourself?

Comment: I have.  I was hoping for something that didn't involve introducing more libraries.  But overall this may be cleaner than the hacks I was beginning to consider. Thanks Bauke

Comment: OmniFaces is not "just" a library :) There's quite some stuff in there that can greatly help in reducing/simplifying your JSF code.

Comment: Actually the OmniFaces home page says it's a "utility library".

Comment: I will check out Omnifaces but keeping additional dependencies to a minimum is a priority.  The alternative I may go with is keeping the FacesConverter declaration, but using an explicit lookup via CDI BeanManager to replace the non-functional Inject annotations.  If only the issue could just be resolved in JSF.  It's been out there a while...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who might be interested in this alternative, I was able to replace the Inject annotations with programmatic lookup via BeanManager in the constructor.  The condensed code is below.  I've not performance tested, and suspect that may be a downside.  If time permits I'll compare to the Omnifaces solution.

EDIT: The cost of the BeanManager lookup turned out to be minimal.  The constructor takes on average <1ms.

```
@FacesConverter(forClass = AbstractEntity.class)
public class EntityConverter implements Converter {

    private LocationService locationService;
    private Class entityClass;

    //Special parameterized constructor for @FacesConverter described in the original question
    public EntityConverter(Class entityClass) throws NamingException {
            this.entityClass = entityClass;
            this.locationService = loadManagedBean(LocationService.class, "locationService");
        }

    //Generic lookup method for @Named managed beans
    protected <T> T loadManagedBean(Class<T> clazz, String beanName) throws NamingException {
            InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
            BeanManager bm = (BeanManager) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");

            Bean<T> bean = (Bean<T>) bm.getBeans(beanName).iterator().next();
            CreationalContext<T> cc = bm.createCreationalContext(bean);
            T beanInstance = (T) bm.getReference(bean, clazz, cc);
            return beanInstance;
    }
}
```