# @Ejb doesn't inject in converter

Tags: jsf, ejb, converters

I'm trying to Write my own converter

I want to Inject my EJBs into my converter with @EJB .
my @EJB works in Other my ManagedBean but it doesn't work here in my converter

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped

public class ServerTypeConverter implements Converter {

@EJB
private ServerTypeFacade serverTypeFacade;


@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    } else {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(value);
        return serverTypeFacade.findById(id);
    }
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    if (value == null || value.equals("")) {
        return "";
    } else {
        Integer id = ((ServerType) value).getServer_type_id();
        return String.valueOf(id);
    }

}


}
```

ServerTypeFacade returns null. why ?

here is the way i use converter

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{serverMB.selectedServerType}">
                    <f:converter converterId="serverTypeConverter"/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{serverMB.serverTypesList}" var="servertypes" itemLabel="#{servertypes.server_type_name}" />
                    <f:ajax listener="#{serverMB.changeServerType}"  render="dd" />


                </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: How are you *using* the converter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@EJB` in converter works only if you declare it as a managed bean by `@ManagedBean` and use it as managed bean by `#{serverTypeConverter}`.

However, you're using the converter as a faces converter by `converterId="serverTypeConverter"`. Apparently you've also declared it as a faces converter by `@FacesConverter` on the class or `<converter>` in `faces-config.xml`.

Those two ways of declaring and using the converter are mutually exclusive. In order to get `@EJB` to work, you should be using the converter as a managed bean:

```
<f:converter binding="#{serverTypeConverter}" />
```

#### See also:

- [CDI Injection into a FacesConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531449/cdi-injection-into-a-facesconverter)

Comment: but when i want to use converter like #{serverTypeConverter}
I get this error  : 
javax.servlet.ServletException: Expression Error: Named Object: com.mb.ServerTypeConverter@3c37114f not found.