# My selectOneMenu select each time last value

Tags: jakarta-ee

why my SelectOneMenu select each time last value

This is my SelectOneMenu code:

```
<p:selectOneMenu   id="marque" style="font-family:Times, serif; font-size:13px;">
                        <f:selectItem   itemLabel="" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{marqueBean.listAllMarque()}" var="item"  itemValue="#{biensBean.biens.setIdmarque(biensBean.biensFacade.getMarque(item.idmarque))}" itemLabel="#{item.libelle}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Please can someone please help me ?

Comment: I use the second proposition. if i execute no error signaled but regidtering reguse. Can help me again please

Answer (score 0):

You either need to implement `javax.faces.convert.Converter` which converts `idmarque` into `Marque` (see for example [CDI Injection into a FacesConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531449/cdi-injection-into-a-facesconverter))

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="biensBean.biens" converter="yourConverter">
 <f:selectItem itemLabel="" />
 <f:selectItems value="#{marqueBean.listAllMarque()}" var="item"
    itemValue="#{item.idmarque}" itemLabel="#{item.libelle}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

or if you just want the selected `idmarque` in `biensBean.biens.idmarque` then you can use

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="biensBean.biens.idmarque" ...>
 <f:selectItem itemLabel="" />
 <f:selectItems value="#{marqueBean.listAllMarque()}" var="item"
    itemValue="#{item.idmarque}" itemLabel="#{item.libelle}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```